# Drawable images resources :used as integers

Tags: android

I was trying to use the image resources in the activity file when i was working with a list view. I realized then R.drawable.image_name was of int type. Why do you think it is like that?

Comment: Everything in `R` is an `int` because it is only an index for bundle resource. Android view supports set int to image.

Answer (score 0):

That is right. Because setImageRecource() method get id of your image drawable in your project and set that iamge resource to your ImageView.